# Why does UIButton target only work when selector is declared in a certain way

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I am really confused as to why the follow only works when I create the UIButton in view did load, Im hoping to get an answer to this because im trying to clean my the viewDidLoad function.

```
let logoutButton: UIBarButtonItem = {
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logoutButton // Does not work
    // navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
}
```

Comment: Where else should this code go?

Comment: How does it not work? It works for me.

Comment: When clicking on the logout button, the handlelogout function is not getting called

Comment: This looks like a Swift bug IMO.

Comment: are you define handleLogout method?

Comment: You should be getting a warning inside the declaration of that button. You cannot access `self` inside that block. You could fix this by making that `let logoutButton` into `lazy var logoutButton`. Then your line in `viewDidLoad` would work.

Comment: That did the trick @Fogmeister! If you make your comment an answer ill mark it as accepted. Yea and it wasnt showing me any warnings